# Jenkins: SCM triggering constant builds despite no change

Tags: version-control, build, triggers, jenkins

We have a problem where despite no code changes SCM is triggering a build. SCM polls for changes every 15 minutes and should only trigger a build if changes are found.

Here are a few examples of consecutive SCM polling log.

```
Started on Nov 15, 2013 11:47:14 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 08f48cc5675ae0126256cf24d6ee74c8fc9d7b30 (origin/develop)
Done. Took 0.23 sec
Changes found

Started on Nov 15, 2013 11:17:14 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 08f48cc5675ae0126256cf24d6ee74c8fc9d7b30 (origin/develop)
Done. Took 0.22 sec
Changes found

Started on Nov 15, 2013 11:02:14 AM
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 08f48cc5675ae0126256cf24d6ee74c8fc9d7b30 (origin/develop)
Done. Took 0.2 sec
Changes found
```

As you can see the revision is the same and matches that of

```
Git Build Data

Revision: 08f48cc5675ae0126256cf24d6ee74c8fc9d7b30 origin/develop
```

These jobs behaved as expected until a few days ago. There is nothing that we're aware that has changed about our environment to cause this.

I upgraded to the latest version of Jenkins (1.539) and installed plug-ins last night in a effort to resolve this but the behavior continues.

Comment: Are you running your builds on a slave that's separate from the Jenkins master ?  Jenkins can sometimes trigger a build if the master is restarted and then can't find a workspace on the slave.  If that's happening, you should see a message something like "Triggering build to get a workspace" in the build log.

Comment: I had a similar issue with svn when the svn server name was uppercase, but svn was remembering as lowercase. So it build every time until I changed the servername to lowercase in the jenkins job.

Answer (score 17):

I just ran into Jenkins continuously building due to an SCM change, even when there was no change, and polling was not even turned on. This may be different from your scenario but I figured it may still help to share my solution.

Out project is configured to build using the branch specifier `*/integration` just like all of our other integration builds. However, after looking at all of the branches on our origin git repo, I saw that there are two branches that matched the `*/integration` specifier. It looks like a developer must have erroneously pushed to a new branch with a very similar name:

```
$git branch --remote | grep integration
  origin/integration
  origin/origin/integration
```

The solution that fixed this issue for me was to specify the branch fully, using `refs/heads/integration`. I assume it would also work to simply delete the duplicate offending branch, but by specifying the branch exactly I can avoid running into the same problem in the future.

I'm not sure this is the same cause for your problem but this is what worked for me, and hopefully will work for someone else in this situation.

Comment: I had this problem even without using *.  putting the branch name as refs/heads/{branch-name} fixed it for me.

Comment: In my case, polling was turned on, but I tried to check if this will help so changes all branch references to `refs/heads/<branch>` syntax, but it made no difference.

Comment: DID NOT WORK FOR ME EITHER. I was having continuous build for months with `*/master` branch with `H/60 * * * * `. Replacing with `origin/master` was not enough, neither was prefixing with `refs/heads/master`. Same solution is discussed at https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30667 but did nothing for me.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to be reproducible with latest [Jenkins GIT plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) version 2.0.

Downgrade to version 1.x may fix the problem. Though you should also revert Jenkins configuration from older backup as GIT plugin version 1.x seems to be not working with new 2.0 configuration scheme.

[This thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/git-polling-builds-every-2-minutes-repository-isn-t-changing-why-td4679352.html) suggests to enable "Fast remote polling" as a workaround. In version 2.0 it's called "Force polling using workspace" I think.

Reference to Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20767

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this same issue today. It started happening when I added the "Delete workspace when build is done" publish task. I removed that task and it seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: I added that  task today. Must be the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.

What fixed it for me is noticing that the Git Polling Log looked like this:

```
Started on [date]
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision [commit#] (origin/develop)
[...]
Found 12 remote heads on ssh://[...]/repo.git
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/feature/foo is: [commit#] - already built by 1414
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/feature/bar is: [commit#] - already built by 2365
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/feature/baz is: [commit#] - already built by 1489
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/feature/qux is: [commit#] - already built by 1413
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/develop is: [commit#] - already built by 2368
[poll] Latest remote head revision on refs/heads/master is: [commit#]
Done. Took 0.16 sec
Changes found
```

Notice that the line for `master` doesn't say 'already built'. I built the `master` branch and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with svn redirections, in my case i had the same case Jenkins could not detect if svn has no changes and allways was triggering.

The problem was that in my jenkins svn configuration had this url:

https://xxxx.yyy.es:443/svn/myproject/trunk and its redirect to

http://xxxx.yyy.es:8008/svn/myproject/trunk (i dont know why)

Jenkins had to be configured with the last URL in order to detect the svn changes properly.

This is my issue Resolved.

http://antuansoft.blogspot.com.es/2014/10/jenkins-pool-smc-always-detect-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Removing the cleanup step at the end of the pipeline did the trick for me:

```
cleanup {
  cleanWs()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another scenario in which this happens, which is if the repository was transferred.
I solved it by manually modifying the git URLs, which were inside the cache files (/caches directory in Jenkins home folder)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do that?