# Jenkins job getting triggered even without commit

Tags: git, jenkins

I have  project in pycharm imported to git hub ( via share project on github). I want the build to be triggered for that project in Jenkins as soon as a commit (git push ) is made. For that I have created a job in jenkins as create item --> free style project --> under SCM I select git an give the url of my project -- > go to build trigger --> poll SCM -- > I give * * * * * as  schedule.

But the problem is the build is getting triggered every minute even without a commit (git push). What should I do ? I have just started to learn Jenkins so not much Idea.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the job or the pipeline to make sure your configuration is OK ?

Comment: Just added pictures of the job configuration . Since I am learning so just created a demo project to build. I have removed poll SCM in the images  but I am adding five stars  in the poll SCM to check and build .

Comment: The build trigger action is missing

Comment: that's what I said when I add build trigger as Poll SCM -->> * * * * *   it is getting triggered every minute regardless of push made to git hub .  Shouldn't it be triggered only when I made a git push ?

Comment: Yep , it should can you upload the console log of the job ?

Comment: added the console output image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171651/discussion-between-vicky-and-mor-lajb).

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/q/20007854/6309 help?